# Android sqlite search data in between dates

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to fetch data from sqlite in between two dates...

My date value stored in sqlite `27/01/2017 15:10:42`

My code to fetch data...

```
 Cursor fetchallconsultations(String from,String to) {       
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("select * from gle_consultns where consultn_create_date >= '"+from+" 00:00:00' and consultn_create_date <= '"+to+" 00:00:00'", null);
}
```

Values of from and to are..

from==`26/01/2017`

to==`01/02/2017`

But the cursor is null when executing `fetchallconsultations` function. How can i resolve this issue.?

Comment: You really should be storing dates and times in ISO8601 format when using SQLite; there are no native date or time types in SQLite, just strings so you need a format that compares sensible as strings.

Comment: How do you store the date in consultn_create_date ?

Comment: @MikeT ive given that in my question

Comment: @muistooshort thanks... I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are stored in a non standard format.  The standard format puts year, month, day, from left to right, in that order.  Hence, the following query should give you the expected results:

```
SELECT *
FROM gle_consultns
WHERE consultn_create_date >= '2017-01-26 00:00:00' AND
      consultn_create_date <= '2017-02-01 00:00:00'
```

You will either need to clean up your date data, or possibly do complex string extractions to build a timestamp of the above form.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date BETWEEN '"+startdate+"' AND '"+enddate+"'";

cursor = db.rawQuery(str, null);

[where date format is startdate=2017-01-26 and enddate=2017-02-01]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
expr BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

and use `selectionArgs`

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Comment: This won't fix the OP's problem, because the dates are in a non comparable format.